# Windows Batch script to redirect stdout to stdin of an EXE we've just run

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

I know the normal behaviour when running an EXE in a batch script is for the batch script to wait for the EXE to exit before continuing, but is there any way to get the batch script to continue execution, but redirect its stdout to the stdin of the EXE?

Basically I'm trying to achieve this neat trick or something similar...

```
@ECHO OFF
echo This is a windows batch script...
dir /p C:\

C:\cygwin\bash.exe <--- Do some magic here

echo This is a bash shell script...
ls -la /cygdrive/c/
exit

echo We're back to the windows batch script again
REM Note: being able to return to the batch script isn't important
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo This is a windows batch script...
dir /p C:\

(
ECHO echo This is a bash shell script...
ECHO ls -la /cygdrive/c/
ECHO exit
) | C:\cygwin\bash.exe

echo We're back to the windows batch script again
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

If you want not to add `ECHO` to each bash line, you may use this method:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo This is a windows batch script...
dir /p C:\

rem Get the number of the first line in this file that start with "###"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^###" "%~F0"') do set "line=%%a" & goto break
:break

rem Pass from that line to end of this file to bash.exe
more +%line% "%~F0" | C:\cygwin\bash.exe 

echo We're back to the windows batch script again
goto :EOF


#################################################################
# The remainder of this file is a bash script running in cygwin #
#################################################################

echo This is a bash script!!
ls -la /cygdrive/c/
```

**EDIT #2**:

I borrowed SonicAtom's method and slightly modified it in order to make it simpler. Here it is:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal

rem This is a magic trick to run the bottom half of this script as a bash script
if not defined _restarted (
    set _restarted=true
    cmd.exe /Q /D < "%~F0"
    rem Put any cleanup commands here
    echo/
    echo Bash script finished
    pause
    exit /B
)
cls
"C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe"

#################################################################
# The remainder of this file is a bash script running in cygwin #
#################################################################

echo This is a bash script!!
ls -la /cygdrive/c/
```

Comment: Ah we posted an answer at the same time! :) This method makes sense, but I don't like having to append `ECHO` to the beginning of every line. My solution is a little more complex but produces cleaner code.

Comment: ... and the Edit #2 also.

Answer (score 0):

No replies?

Well I found the answer myself:

test.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF

rem This is a magic trick to run the bottom half of this script as a bash script
if not exist _.bat (
    echo @ECHO OFF >_.bat
    echo cmd.exe -c ^< %~nx0 >>_.bat
    _.bat
    rem Put any cleanup commands here
    del _.bat
    echo.
    echo Bash script finished
    pause
    exit /B
)
cls
"C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe"

#################################################################
# The remainder of this file is a bash script running in cygwin #
#################################################################

echo This is a bash script!!
ls -la /cygdrive/c/
```

**How it works:**

The file starts off as a batch script. It writes another (temporary) batch script which runs another cmd.exe shell, directing the original batch file to cmd.exe as stdin. The original batch file then acts like a text file containing commands typed on the keyboard. It runs bash.exe, and continues to provide stdin to bash. The only disadvantage is that the @ECHO OFF doesn't take effect in the part of the batch file that runs before bash.exe is called. This is because there doesn't seem to be a way to turn off keyboard echoing in cmd.exe.

Comment: I am afraid your method does not work for this reason: After bash.exe ends execution, the Batch file continue with the next line, so it mark error in each bash line.

Comment: Ok. I reviewed your code and my previous comment was wrong. However, you need to execute the second Batch file via a CALL command: `call _.bat`; otherwise, the control does _not_ return to the original file and the cleanup code will not be executed. (What a complicated method to do this!)

Comment: Well actually my method did work including the clean-up code, I know because I was using it. But I prefer your 1st edit answer above, that's so much cleaner and more elegant! Thanks! :)