# Reading STDIN in Java that was started from a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, stdin

I have a console Java application, that depends on a lot of `jar` package. Therefore, I put all these packages in a batch file together. The only problem is, that if I start the Java app from the batch file I can't read from `STDIN`. I mean, I would like to process some user input, that was typed on the console, but nothing happens in the app.

To start the app from within the batch, I use this code (based upon this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015036/windows-batch-script-to-redirect-stdout-to-stdin-of-an-exe-weve-just-run)):

```
setlocal
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do (
  #%%a java  -classpath ...
)
```

If I just invoke the Java app from the batch without the `FOR` loop, I also can't access to `STDIN`.

If I start the app directly from cmd, I can read from `STDIN` without any problems.

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-standard-input-in-java/) is the code I am using to read from `STDIN`.

I really would like to use a batch file, because the command-line for the Java app is very long.

Is there a trick to redirect the `STDIN` to Java, or at least to a file ?

Comment: Why do you use more (like this)? It captures stdin and does not pass it to any subcommand (java in your case). It might be better to use `java -cp ... | more` instead, but even then the resulting batch file is hard to use for scripting. (and the purpose of the tokens parsing is not clear to me at all)

Comment: Don't have the answer but this is not a java question, it's a cmd batch question. You want to redirect cmd batch stdin to the process called from within the batch.

Comment: The `FOR` loop you have used doesn't make any sense,The `more` command captures the `stdin` and blocks the execution of the batch code until it terminates by pressing `CTRL-Z` (or `CTRL-C`) then you have `#%%a java -classpath ...` it would be translated to `#WhatEverHaveBeenCapturedByMore java -classpath ...`. What are you trying to achieve with that? Did you get that code from someone or wrote it yourself? `"If i start the app directly from cmd.exe, i can read from STDIN without any problems."` Just do the same in the batch file as you did in CMD prompt.

Comment: I added the thread, i used to build the batch command. My first try was to invoke the Java app from the batch without the <code>FOR</code> loop, but it didn't work. Then i thought maybe it have to be forced, so i used <code>more</code>. I would like to access to STDIN from the Java app, that is invoked from the batch, but it seems, the batch is blocking Java from doing that.

Comment: My next try was to use the command `start` to execute the Java application in an other window. This worked well. But after this, i realized that invoking the Java app directly from a batch also worked. I have no imagination, what could be the problem.